# How to filter an ng-repeat by clicking on link in repeated template

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat. I want to be able to click a link inside any of the items to filter the list to only that item. How can this be accomplished?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <a ng-click="?">Select this one</a>
</div>
```

Items are have unique ids:

```
$scope.items = [
  {id: 1}
  {id: 2}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter`, and make sure you use `$parent` to refer to the `selected` model in the parent scope since `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each repeated item.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:selected"> 
    <a ng-click="$parent.selected=item">
        Select this one {{item}}
    </a>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2RUUX/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I don't think the ng-model is useful on a link. Beside that, this is the way to do it :)

Comment: @Galdo Yeah. I was just about to remove that. Thanks.